# MPI peer-to-peer communications: order of messages

Tags: mpi

I've read that MPI preserves message order. But the exact meaning of this is not clear to me.

Suppose that process A sends two messages (message 1 and then message 2) with different tags to process B in buffered mode. Process B posts two matching receive calls in inverted order. Is it possible that message 2 be received sooner than message 1?

Comment: It depends what you mean exactly by "received sooner". If you use blocking recv, then the first `MPI_Recv(..., tag=tag2, ...)` will receive message2, and the following `MPI_Recv(..., tag=tag1, ...)` will receive message1. message1 might have "arrived" before message2 on the node, but it will be delivered to your app (via `MPI_Recv()` after.

Comment: Thanks, @GillesGouaillardet. Here I was interested to know the order in which the messages can be sent and received by the processes that call MPI functions, not the way the MPI implementation manages them internally. The first part of your comment provides an answer.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, so the receive order can be different from the send order, without leading to a deadlock (I've assumed that the sends are all non-blocking, and all the receives are blocking) . That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Keep in mind a correct MPI program never assumes `MPI_Send()` returns before a matching receive is posted.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, yes. That's why I used the phrase "buffered mode" in the question. Thanks.